# Analogue Camera Olympus OM-1 in space?

Tags: space-shuttle, photography, camera

Was analogue 35 mm camera Olympus OM-1 really in space? I read this article about this topic: http://elrectanguloenlamano.blogspot.com/2016/06/olympus-om-1-nasa-recognition-of.html?m=1

According to the article, 5 pieces of Olympus OM1 space prototype cameras were made and 3 of them were given to NASA. These cameras were ordered by Nasa to be used on Columbia space shuttle in 1981 and also on subsequent missions. My question is: were these Olympus cameras really used on Columbia missions? Maybe Nasa ordered them from Olympus, but they later changed their minds and used another cameras. I know about Hasseblads and Nikons in space. I know Leica and Minolta Hi-matic were first cameras in space. But I never heard about Olympus OM-1. Does anyone know more about it? Do you know some books or articles about analogue photography in space? Thanks.

Comment: Here are two links: https://filmphotograph.com/olympus-om-1-nasa-1980  https://historical.ha.com/itm/explorers/space-exploration/space-shuttle-olympus-om-1-camera-body-modified-for-nasa-one-of-five-made/a/6146-52164.s  seems to be trustworthy

Comment: It's a bit weird that *Goddard* would be buying cameras for shuttle though, unless they were associated with Hubble somehow.

Comment: This inflight photo shows the camera equipment for the first Hubble mission. Perhaps someone knowledgeable can ID the cameras.  https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s31-06-035/s31-06-035~orig.jpg

Comment: on the inflight photo some Hasselblad film magazines are easy to identify. There is a Sony audio cassette recorder and a light meter to get optimal exposure with the Hasselblads without an internal light meter. There is a binocular telescope but I see nothing that looks like a 35 mm OM-1.

Comment: Thanks for reply!I don't know why it is weird that Goddard bought Olympus Cameras? (I am a photographer, I don't understand engineering).I think they didn't have these cameras for scientific purpose. They have them for documenting themselves. There are just Hasselblads on inflight photo 
from Hubble mission - but the Olympus is missing here maybe because THIS photo of Hasselblad magazines was made on Olympus. It has a format of 35 mm camera. The photos from 1981 mission (for examp. astronaut Cripen floating in space) have also 35 mm format, but I am not sure, that they were made on Olympus

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=STS-1+In-flight+activities+of+Young+and+Crippen+in+the+cockpit+and+middeck+STS-1+Credit:+NASA&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&prmd=ivn&sxsrf=ALiCzsbFbHFwI1kg51ETNdGtN1mVWJOR6A:1662736378419&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq_MLZ_4f6AhU7XvEDHYIzBegQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=412&bih=775&dpr=2.63#imgrc=DlX6y4Ap-wCOtM&imgdii=hQHIhRZJY5Q5WM